# Getting values of EllipticK with arguments that are very near 1

Tags: special-functions, numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

I need to evaluate `EllipticK[m]` very close to 1. However, when I get too close to 1 the function defaults to the exact solution for 1 , which is `ComplexInfinity`. I can enter a comparable number in Wolfram|Alpha and get both the exact and the numerical approximation, but nothing I have tried gets me that approximate number in Mathematica:

Wolfram|Alpha:

```
EllipticK[0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999]
```

> ```
> 54.3458...
> ```

Mathematica:

```
EllipticK[0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999]
```

> ```
> ComplexInfinity
> ```

```
EllipticK[0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999]//N
```

> ```
> ComplexInfinity
> ```

I've tried various other combinations of precision manipulation as well, so far nothing has worked. Does anyone know how to override the exact answer?

#### Edit

I discovered half the solution immediately after posting. When I put a 0 at the end of the string of 9s, it will evaluate the decimal approximation. However, I don't know how to implement this for the purpose of, say, plotting the `EllipticK`.

Comment: Try `EllipticK[0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999`50]`

Comment: Somos means EllipticK[0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999`50]. The editing is wonky with the backticks, and I don't remember how to escape them.

Comment: @march Use double back-ticks: ``EllipticK[0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999`50]``

Answer (score 1):

Your choice to evaluate `EllipticK[m]` for values of `m` near the [logarithmic singularity at $1$](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/06/01/04/01/0006/) is doomed from the start. The numerically proper way to go about this is to use the [relationship of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind with the arithmetic-geometric mean](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/26/03/04/0001/), so that you are evaluating an argument near $0$:

```
N[Pi/(2 ArithmeticGeometricMean[1, Sqrt[1*^-46]]), 20]
   54.345751499982941351
```

Comment: (I'm not quite back yet, I still don't have my own computer, and I just evaluated this on Wolfram One only to answer this question.)

Comment: Glad you're at least partially back.  Looking forward to you being fully back.